# Count if avg is below/above X

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the number of **'critics'** and **'promoters'** from average of **ratings** from a joined table on a specific group of **questions**

```
     SELECT category
          , SUM( IF( round(avg(items.value) ) <= 6, 1, 0) ) AS critics
          , SUM( IF( round(avg(items.value) ) >= 9, 1, 0) ) AS promoters
     FROM reviews
     INNER JOIN items 
             ON reviews.id = items.review_id 
            AND items.question_id in (1, 2, 4)
     GROUP BY category
```

However I get the **error**:

```
General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` and not `GROUPBY`

Comment: `GROUP BY` — two words

Comment: Thanks, however this is not the issue. Just a typo :) It works just fine if i remove the "SUM... from select"

Comment: please provide table structure with sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with using  **having** with it, something like below:

```
SELECT
   category,
   COUNT(items.id) AS critics
  FROM reviews
   INNER JOIN items ON reviews.id = items.review_id AND 
   items.question_id IN (1, 2, 4)
  GROUP BY category 
  HAVING ROUND(AVG(items.value)) <= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

First **retrieve** category wise rounded **average** value and then apply **condition** either it is **critics** and **promoters**.

```
   -- MySQL
   SELECT t.category
        , CASE WHEN t.avg_value <= 6
                  THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END critics
        , CASE WHEN t.avg_value >= 9
                  THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END promoters
   FROM (SELECT category
              , ROUND(AVG(items.value)) avg_value
         FROM reviews
         INNER JOIN items 
                 ON reviews.id = items.review_id 
                AND items.question_id IN (1, 2, 4)
         GROUP BY category) t
```

Please check this url for finding out pseudocode https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2679b2be50c3059c73ab9754c612179c

First **retrieve** category and review_id wise rounded **average** value and then apply **condition** either it is **critics** and **promoters**.

```
SELECT t.category
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.avg_value <= 6
                   THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) critics
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.avg_value >= 9
                   THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) promoters
FROM (SELECT category
           , items.review_id
           , ROUND(AVG(items.value)) avg_value
      FROM reviews
      INNER JOIN items 
              ON reviews.id = items.review_id 
             AND items.question_id IN (1, 2, 4)
      GROUP BY category
             , items.review_id) t
GROUP BY t.category
```

Comment: thx, however this only return 1 if there is a critic/promoter in the review. Now how many of the reviews where the items avg is <=6 / >=9. Would need something like SUM(CASE WHEN t.avg_value <= 6
                  THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END critics) However that does not work.

Comment: Please provide few sample input and output